# Access Android device via ADB with DEBUG mode OFF

Tags: android, adb

I am just wondering if anyone one knows a method to access/get into an Android tablet (adb shell) if the USB DEBUG mode is off.

I have these devices that I gotta recalibrate the screens but I cannot seem to be able to click anything as the calibration is way off and USB DEBUG has been switched off. Bluetooth is off as well. Moreover screen is not responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect through WiFi or Ethernet.
If the ADB server is started on the tablet, you can run "adb connect IP_ADDR:PORT",  PORT is optional, default 5555 and depends on your ADB server.